Multithreaded sparse linear solver in Python
I would like to know if there are any multithreaded sparse linear solvers for LU decomposed sparse matrices.
I want to increase the solving speed of a system like:
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import diags
import scipy.sparse.linalg as spla

n = 1_000_000  
diagonals = [-0.01*np.ones(n-1), np.ones(n), -0.01*np.ones(n-1)]
offsets = [-1, 0, 1]  

mat = diags(diagonals, offsets, shape=(n, n), format='csc')

LU_mat = spla.splu(mat)  

b = np.random.randn(n)

for i in range(654):
    b = LU_mat.solve(b) 

Where LU decomposition is performed once, and solved "n" times.
On my machine, this example appears to be single threaded.
Are there any Python libraries with multithreaded solvers, so that I can take advantage of the resources of my machine?

What I can do for you and give you suggestions

Use library like Numba or similar;
try to use superlu_dist, uses optimize algorithms (install it using conda);
try Pypy is a JIT compiler;
prefer if is possible numpy.

